# Nuxt components from layers are not typed

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js, layer, volar

I have a Nuxt monorepo.

Applications are into a `apps` folder and layers into a `layers` folder
I have two layers, `layer1` and `layer2`. And two apps `app1` and `app2`.

```
apps
| app1
| app2
layers
| layer1
| layer2
```

The `layer2` is extending the `layer1`. Inside the `layer2`, components auto-imported from the `layer1` are rightfully typed.

However `app1` and `app2` are both extending `layer1` and `layer2`. But inside the apps, only methods used into `<script>` are auto-imported and typed but components used into `<template>` are not typed.

Below, an example of a `nuxt.config.ts` of one of the app

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  extends: ['../../layers/layer1', '../../layers/layer2'],
  app: {
    head: {
      ...
    },
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
     ...
  },
  components: {
    dirs: [
      {
        path: '~/components',
        pathPrefix: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  typescript: {
    shim: false,
    includeWorkspace: true,
  },
  build: {
    transpile: [...],
  },
  modules: [...],
  // ... other config related to modules
})
```

The applications are working correctly but the question is why components auto-imported are not typed?